# TypeError: invalid type comparison during subseting a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In my python application, I have a datframe (`da`) which includes a feature called `Gender`.

```
da = pd.DataFrame({"Gender" : np.random.choice(["Male","Female"],10)})
```

It includes `Male`, or `Female`. When I try to subset it with the below code it:

```
da.loc[(da.Gender == "Male"),["Gender"]]
```

Then, it complains with:

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: You may have missing values try `da.loc[da['Gender'].dropna()=='Male','Gender]`. I just tried your code and I cannot reproduce, you need to post your real data that reproduces this problem

Comment: For me, it works fine..